# Explicit Fuchsian group of surface of genus $g$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, covering-spaces

I am learning hyperbolic geometry on my own. I want to learn Fuchsian groups.

Let $\Sigma_g$ be a geuns $g$ Riemann surface with $g \geq 2$, $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ denotes the fundamental group of $\Sigma_g$. Now $\mathbb{H}/\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ can be thought as $\Sigma_g$ where an element of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ can be thought of as a biholomorphism of upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$. That is equivalent to finding the explicit description of genus $g$ surface as the upper half plane modulo group of Deck Transformation.

My question: Can I study (or get) Fuschian group from the construction? Is Fuchsian group related to it?

I want to study Fuchian group. Please help me.

Thanking in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fuchian groups are (by definition) discrete subgroups of PSL($2$, $\mathbb{R}$), and this is isomorphic to Aut($\mathbb{H}$), the group of biholomorphic maps from $\mathbb{H}$ to $\mathbb{H}$. As you mentioned, there is a connection between subgroups of automorphisms that act properly discontinuously induce a quotient that is a covering map $\mathbb{H} \rightarrow \Sigma_g$.

One of the requirements for a properly discontinuous action is that the subgroup of Aut($\mathbb{H}$) acting must be a discrete subgroup, and hence you get the Fuschian groups. Now, the Riemann surfaces that are covered by the half-plane are called **hyperbolic surfaces**, because you can induce the metric using the covering map.

This gives you a relation between Hyperbolic Riemann Surfaces and Fuschian Groups.

The book "*Riemann Surfaces*", by Hershell M. Farkas and Irwan Kra study some relations about these groups and the corresponding Riemann Surface in the chapter IV, specially IV.5. This may be a good starting point.

Comment: Do you know how to make clear for which (closed) hyperbolic polygons $P\subset \Bbb{H}$ there are finitely many Möbius transformations sending one edge to the other such that when used as transition charts they give a compact Riemann surface structure on $P$ and those Möbius transformations generate a discrete subgroup $G$ of $PSL(2,\Bbb{R})$ such that $P= G\backslash \Bbb{H}$ ?

Comment: I haven't study these in a very long time, but there's the Poincaré Polygon Theorem, that relates these two notions. A good reference for this discussion is John H. Hubbard's book  Teichmüller Theory And Applications To Geometry, Topology, And Dynamics, Theorem 3.9.5.

Comment: Another cool reference for this is https://math.la.asu.edu/~paupert/CriderPoincarePolygonTheorem.pdf. The proof of this theorem actually gives you some methods of finding the generators of the Fuschian Group associated with the polygon.

Comment: Great, I would never have found those $2\pi / m_\mathcal{E}$ 'proper elliptic cycles' myself

Comment: @user454229: If you have detailed followup questions like in your last comment, it is much better to put the question into a new post, rather than to bury it in a comment to an answer to an old post where very few users of this site will see it.